# convert pygame image load surface to gtk get_pixels

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have Code1 and at the end I want co continue with Code2 (both codes are included here). In Code2 I am doing data conversion with get_pixels(). I am trying take last_frame or frame_cache data and then I want to do get_pixels() on it to get the same data format as in Code2.

Any idea please how to do it in my Code1?

Code 1:

```
#we will process only one frame at the time
msgs = self.cap.read()
msgl = len(msgs)
if msgl:
    msg = msgs[msgl - 1]
    cmd = msg[0]

    if cmd == "data":
        data = cStringIO.StringIO(msg[1])
        last_frame = pygame.image.load(data)
        self.frame_update = True

for msg in self.adb.read():
    cmd = msg[0]
    if cmd == "end":
        self.exit()

self.menu_loop()

if self.frame_update:
    self.frame_update = False

    if last_frame is not None:
        if self.landscape:       
            a = last_frame.subsurface(pygame.Rect((0,0), self.sizel))
        else:
            a = last_frame.subsurface(pygame.Rect((0,0), self.sizep))

        aw, ah = a.get_size()
        if aw != self.proj[2] or ah != self.proj[3]:
            frame_cache = pygame.transform.smoothscale(a, (self.proj[2], self.proj[3]))
        else:
            frame_cache = a.copy()

    self.screen_update = True

if self.screen_update:
    self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))   
    self.screen_update = False
    self.screen.blit(frame_cache, (self.proj[0], self.proj[1]))   
    if self.show_menu:
        self.screen.blit(self.img_menu, (0, 0))
    if self.show_nav:
        self.screen.blit(self.img_nav, (self.size[0] - self.nav_w, 0))

    pygame.display.update() #here i need to change it for gtk get_pixels
```

Code 2:

```
img_width = 160
img_height = 120

data = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(
  gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,
  False,
  8,
  img_width,
  img_height 
)  
data.get_from_drawable(
  gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window(),
  gtk.gdk.colormap_get_system(),
  280, 228, 0, 0, 
  img_width, 
  img_height 
)
data = data.scale_simple(width, height, gtk.gdk.INTERP_NEAREST)

data = data.get_pixels()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a one line solution `data = pygame.image.tostring(frame_cache , 'RGB')` does the job